# Is it possible to overwrite the ENTRYPOINT of a docker image while running it from the docker CLI?

Tags: wordpress, docker, entry-point

Is it possible to overwrite the ENTRYPOINT of a docker image while running it from the docker CLI? For example, I am attempting to set some environment variables prior to the `ENTRYPOINT` running for the WordPress image. The environment variables I am trying to assign are `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST`, `WORDPRESS_DB_USER`, `WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD`, etc. The catch is that these environment variables need to be assigned on the running container and not in the local shell.

Comment: Why not use `-e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=...` as a parameter to docker?

Comment: or `docker run --entrypoint` see the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/ extract `--entrypoint=""               Overwrite the default ENTRYPOINT of the image`

Comment: I am trying to set the variables to variables that exist on the container, since the container has the database credentials, but when I set the WORDPRESS env vars to the string values of the var names (rather than their value) it never seems to get evaluated on the running container. For example, when done with --entrypoint one of the variables is set like so "-e WORDPRESS_DB_USER='${VCAP_SERVICES_CLEARDB_0_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME}'" but it is never evaluated on the running container.

Comment: Once the database has been initialized, those variables should not be changed; because the password etc has already been set. You can still connect to the database using the old credentials and update them though

Comment: The application will be on IBM's cloud platform Bluemix, which happen to inject the MySQL database credentials into the running container via a different environment variable. I know I can get it working by reading these credentials and setting the variables from my run command, but my goal was to avoid needing to copy-paste them into the run command.